# Entry titles that start with X,Y, or Z do not show up on page

Tags: channel-entries, entries, title

Hey everyone this is a weird issue I hope I can get some clarification.

Firstly, this is EE 2.2.0.

One of our pages cannot show entries that have a title that starts with X,Y,or Z.  All other letters work.  There is nothing complex in the code to exclude any letters or anything like that.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="add-job" orderby="title" sort="asc"}
{if job-type == "Full-Time"}

<h4><a href="{title_permalink='/employment/job-detail/'}">{title}</a></h4>
<ul>
{related_entries id="Willson"}<li> Camp Willson</li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="delawarey-staff-contact222"}<li>Delaware Community Center </li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="Downtown"}<li>Downtown </li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="ELC"}<li> Early Learning Center</li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="ECRN"}<li>ECRN+</li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="Ward"}<li>Eldon & Elsie Ward Family </li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="gahanna-staff-contact"}<li>Gahanna </li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="grovecity-branch-contact"}<li>Grove City </li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="hilliard-branch-contact"}<li>Hilliard </li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="hilltop-branch-contact"}<li>Hilltop </li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="hilltopeducare-branch-contact"}<li> Hilltop Educare</li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="cherrycreek-branch-contact"}<li>Hilltop /Cherry Creek</li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="hoover-branch-contact"}<li>Hoover Y Park</li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="garver-branch-contact"}<li>Jerry L. Garver </li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="liberty-branch-contact"}<li>Liberty Township/Powell </li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="metro-contact"}<li>Metropolitan Offices</li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="north-branch-contact"}<li>North </li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="pals-contact"}<li>PALS/Juvenile Justice</li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="pickaway-branch-contact"}<li>Pickaway County Family </li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="stanns-branch-contact"}<li> St. Ann's Educare</li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="sunshine-branch-contact"}<li>Franklin Station</li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="vaughn-branch-contact"}<li>Vaughn E. Hairston </li>{/related_entries}
{related_entries id="van-buren-center-contact"}<li>Van Buren Center</li>{/related_entries}
</ul>

{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I can take an entry that doesn't work, change the title to "T" or really any other letter, and it will work.  When I make test entries that just say X,Y, or Z, nothing works.

Comment: How many entries do you have? I see you have no `limit` on your `channel:entries` tag - try adding `limit="5000"`.

Comment: I support what Derek Hogue said; the default `limit` is 100, so your last 10-15-whatever entries start with X, Y, and Z, but are in the 100 to 115 entry count range. That's why if you change an X to a T, it is suddenly number 80 in the title sort.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!  This is the second time the default entry limit got me.  I need to remember this.

The solution was, in fact, setting the entry limit to a higher number.